# php str_word_count

Tags: php

I am trying to count the number words in paragraphs of texts. Right now I'm using `str_word_count`, which is going great except the single quotation marks are messing things up.

The function is counting `'propter'` and `propter` as different words. It is also counting `et'` and `et`, `'non` and `non` as different words.

How can I get the function to ignore the single quotations. The text is all in latin so there are no instances of single quotations within words (if that makes any difference).

Comment: Have you tried to use `str_replace("'", '', $str)` before you use `str_word_cound`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly hacky solution, but you should be able to do:

```
$count = str_word_count(str_replace("'",'',$str));
```

...and get the answer you want, given the example problems above.

**EDIT**

If you are trying to get the number of unique words in the passage, as suggested by Pablo M. Prieto, you can do it like this:

```
$count = count(array_unique(str_word_count(strtolower(str_replace("'",'',$str)),1)));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always remove the single quotation marks before using the `str_word_count()`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that is the default behavior of `str_word_count()` function. It counts the amount of words in the paragraph.

So if you have:

```
$paragraph = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 'lorem' ipsum 'dolor'";
```

and

```
$paragraph = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor";
```

it will return int(8) for both of them.

Were you trying to count the amount of unique words in the paragraph?